# Merge sort function C# not sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, mergesort

I've been trying to build a merge sort algorithm, that sorts a list of numbers but cannot seem to get it to work. The functions look like this at the moment:

```cs
private void Merge_sort(List<int> list, int left, int right)
{
    if (left < right)
    {
        int center = (left + right) / 2;
        Merge_sort(list, left, center);
        Merge_sort(list, center + 1, right);
        Merge(list, left, center, right);
    }
}

private void Merge(List<int> list, int left, int center, int right)
{
    int num1 = center - left + 1;
    int num2 = right - center;

    List<int> left_list = new List<int>();
    List<int> right_list = new List<int>();

    for (int ii = left; ii <= center; ii++)
    {
        left_list.Add(ii);
    }
    for (int jj = center + 1; jj < right; jj++)
    {
        right_list.Add(jj);
    }
    left_list[num1 + 1] = int.MaxValue;
    right_list[num2 + 1] = int.MaxValue;
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;

    for (int k = left; k < right; k++)
    {
        if (left_list[i] <= right_list[j])
        {
            list[k] = left_list[i];
            i= i+1;
        }
        else
        {
            list[k] = right_list[j];
            j = j+1;
        }
    }
}
```

the function that calls these ones is:

```cs
public override void Sort(List<int> list)
{
    //find the center
    int center = list.Count / 2;
    int right = center;
    int left = center;
    Merge_sort(list, left, right);
}
```

can anyone see what I am doing wrong? The program runs, it just doesn't sort the list.

Comment: `if(left < right)` you init both with `center`... so this will always be false and sorting never ever even starts. Which you would have probably seen, had you stepped it through. Make yourself familiar with the debugging tools :)

Answer (score 0):

`if(left < right)` you init both with `center`, so this will *always* be `false` and sorting never ever even starts.

Which you would have probably seen, had you stepped it through. Make yourself familiar with the debugging tools :)

To fix this, try ...

```
public override void Sort(List<int> list)
{
    // TODO Check Count > 1 , maybe even > 2 for 2 elements you simply need an if/else
    int right = list.Count-1;
    int left = 0;
    Merge_sort(list, left, right);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid there are many more problems in the OP's code...

Comment: @chqrlie correct. But at least it will do _something_.